# Trying to print lines by specific column value in awk

Tags: regex, select, awk

I have a file with 400M records. I am trying to write out individual files if they match sctg2 = n where n = 1 to 43. scgt2 is the 5th column. The sample CSV file **(samplef.csv)** is available here: http://goo.gl/if85vJ

```
ofips, dfips, ofaf, dfaf, sctg2, tons, value
1001,1001,1,1,1,10,20
1001,1002,1,1,1,20,30
1001,1003,1,1,1,30,40
1001,1004,1,1,1,40,50
1001,1001,1,1,2,110,20
1001,1002,1,1,2,120,30
1001,1003,1,1,2,130,40
1001,1004,1,1,2,140,50
1001,1001,1,1,3,210,20
1001,1002,1,1,3,220,30
1001,1003,1,1,3,230,40
1001,1004,1,1,3,240,50
```

I used awk (Windows 7) and I have tried the following expressions where it will only select those records where sctg2 = 2(all of which give the output as an empty file):

```
gawk '$5 == 2 {print $1, $2, $6, $7}' samplef.csv > sampleout.csv
gawk '$5 ~ /2/ {print $1, $2, $6, $7}' samplef.csv > sampleout.csv
```

The expected output **(sampleout.csv)** is:

```
ofips, dfips, tons, value
1001,1001,110,20
1001,1002,120,30
1001,1003,130,40
1001,1004,140,50
```

Any help is appreciated, as I am not sure what I am doing wrong here and am at my wits' end. Does the fact that it is a CSV or the regex pattern numeric have any bearing on this?

TIA,

Krishnan

Comment: What shell are you running this in? is it cmd.exe? If yes, then you need double quotes: single quotes have no special meaning in cmd.exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, awk uses whitespace to separate 
columns.  If you want to use commas, try:

```
gawk '$5 == 2 {print $1, $2, $6, $7}' FS=, samplef.csv > sampleout.csv
```

FS is the field separator, and setting it to a comma should do what you want.  There are several techniques for setting the value, and each of the following is equivalent.  (There are subtle differences between these and the form shown above, but those differences are irrelevant to this particular example).

```
awk -v FS=, '$5 == 2 {print $1, $2, $6, $7}'
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} $5 == 2 {print $1, $2, $6, $7}'
awk -F , '...'
```

Comment: You need to set `OFS` to `,` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1||NR>1&&$5==2{print $1,$2,$6,$7}' OFS=, file
```

#### Output with your file

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==1||NR>1&&$5==2{print $1,$2,$6,$7}' OFS=, file
ofips, dfips, tons, value
1001,1001,110,20
1001,1002,120,30
1001,1003,130,40
1001,1004,140,50
```